# Material Ui Autocomplete - Filtering options is not working as expected

Tags: reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I have Autocomplete where I pass an array of fetched and predefined options...
https://codesandbox.io/s/geocoding-demo-forked-2f189?file=/src/App.js

When I type e.g. "Diestsestraat Leuven" it doesn't display any options, but when I console.log it I see array of options.
[image]

- I fixed this with this answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/68506363/16002090
  (I added - `filterOptions={(options) => options}` and it displays list of options...)

But then it doesn't filter out predefined options (see screenshot)

[image]

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my case, I tried adding key to **renderOption** solutions. Reference: [here](https://lockstep.io/blog/debugging-lesson-well-learned-fixing-material-ui-autocomplete-search/)

```
 <Autocomplete
        ...
          renderOption={(props, item) => (
                  <li {...props} key={item.key}>
                    <ListItemText>{item.label}</ListItemText>
                  </li>
        )
  />
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Helped my a lot today with you Link:) Maybe try to reformat your code so that it is readable 

Comment: "key" was the solution thank you 

Comment: This was super helpful. In my case, I didn't even need to use render-option earlier. After reading the reply & the link, I simply used render-option with key, and the displayed options were filtered accurately. Awesome !

Answer (score 3):

You can use filterOptions prop in Autocomplete component. It gives you 2 parameter. First one is the options you've given to it and second one is the state of the input component. So you can customize it with your own filterize:

```
const filterOptions = (options, state) => {
    let newOptions = [];
    options.forEach((element) => {
      if (
        element.place_name
          .replace(",", "")
          .toLowerCase()
          .includes(state.inputValue.toLowerCase())
      )
        newOptions.push(element);
    });
    return newOptions;
  };
```

[image: Edit geocoding-demo (forked)]

Comment: Here is a search term to check - Diestsestraat Leuven

Comment: @Nikita Updated answer. Please check. It was because options has `,` in the term which you need to remove it for your purpose!

Comment: Not sure it’s the best solution -   .replace(",", "")....

Comment: @Nikita So you need to achieve your aim with this term : `Diestsestraat, Leuven`!

Comment: Please check out this link : `https://appdividend.com/2020/08/01/javascript-remove-character-from-string-example/`. `replace` is one of the solutions to remove a character from string.

Comment: @Nikita Because you're filtering a list of strings with a string which you would like to filter it event it has `,` character, so you need to remove it from the string to filter.

Answer (score 0):

So on the `filterOptions` you are only returning options where you should be filtering.
You could try adding:

```
filterOptions={(options) =>
  options.filter(({ place_name }) => place_name.includes(query))
}
```

Comment: When you type - “Diestsestraat Leuven” - it doesn't display any options, but when I console.log it I see array of options.

Comment: I provided link to the playground, so you can see yourself...

Comment: The only option that is available is `Diestsestraat, Leuven` - notice the `,`.

Answer (score -1):

```
 renderOption={(props, item) => (
            <li {...props} key={item.key}>
                    {item.name}     
            </li>           
    )}


replace item.name with your render values
```

Comment: did not work for me