# MUI Autocomplete filterOptioms still displaying all options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

**Hello everyone,**

A bit of a weird one now. I have a heavily customized Autocomplete due to restrictions and other use-cases. I now have an issue with the filter. It's still displaying all options available. I console.logged the filter result itself and this does correctly work. When I log it I only see the filtered values. THing is, all options stay displayed. None are filtered.

In short;

- When I log the result from filterOptions it is correct. For example, I search for "Netherlands", it only displays the relevant result. `options.filter()` does it's job right.
- This results are not displayed. The Autocomplete still shows all values.

What's going wrong here? Do I handle something wrong or is something else at play?

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={allCountries}
  onChange={(event, newValue) => {
    if (!newValue || !newValue[1] || !newValue[1].phone) return;

    setPrefix(newValue[1].phone);
  }}
  value={allCountries.find(
    (nestedArray) => nestedArray[1].phone === prefix
  )}
  autoHighlight
  getOptionLabel={(option) => `+${option[1].phone}`}
  renderOption={(props, option) => (
    <Box
      component="li"
      sx={{ "& > img": { mr: 2, flexShrink: 0 } }}
      {...props}
    >
      <img
        width="20"
        src={`https://flagcdn.com/w20/${option[0].toLowerCase()}.png`}
      />
      {option[1].name} (+{option[1].phone})
    </Box>
  )}
  filterOptions={(options, state) => {
    if (state.inputValue === "") return options;

    const query = state.inputValue.toLowerCase();

    return options.filter((option) => {
      return `${option[1].name.toLowerCase()} (+${
        option[1].phone
      })`.includes(query);
    });
  }}
  renderInput={(params) => (
    <TextField
      {...params}
      label="Prefix"
      inputProps={{
        ...params.inputProps,
      }}
    />
  )}
/>
```

Comment: can you console.log(state) from filterOptions.

Comment: @Samira Of course. When I search for `Netherl` I'll get `{inputValue: 'Netherl', getOptionLabel: ƒ}` The result when I console.log is indeed the value. The filter seems to be working, but not rendering.

Comment: for future readers / searchers, try looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75724932/13658816) also. It was useful to me. Basically, I needed to add render-option and specify unique key for each option. Once this was done, the options list got filtered properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [allCountries, setAllCountries] = useState([
                                                  //initial Options 
                                                 ]);
const onChange= (inputValue )=>{
   if (inputValue === "") return options;

const query = inputValue.toLowerCase();

let list = options.filter((option) => {
  return `${option[1].name.toLowerCase()} (+${
    option[1].phone
  })`.includes(query);
});
 setAllCountries(state=>(list))

}
```

autocomplete props:

```
onChange={(e, value) => onChange(value)}
```

Comment: Well, inputValue is its own internal value for the dearch option. It’s not the final value. How could the results still be correct if this was the issue? 

The results are correct, they are just not correctly rendered.

Comment: I think I could understand your problem and I changed my answer.
you need to use onChange because that will render

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you're updating only the `value` prop after the prefix has been changed. But, besides that you have to update the `inputValue` prop too, which is responsible for the value displayed in the textbox:

```
const [inputValue, setInputValue] = React.useState('');

...
    inputValue={inputValue}
    onInputChange={(event, newInputValue) => {
        setInputValue(newInputValue);
    }}
...
```